Is there a more efficient way to check if VsCode (or any other editor) is installed on the device where my program is being run?

I have this function check_editor_installed which checks if a specified code editor is installed on the user's device.
I use..
snprintf(check_command, sizeof(check_command), "which %s", editor_command);
because I assume "code" is the command used to launch VSCode.
This is the full function:
int check_editor_installed(const char *editor_command) {
    char check_command[256];
    snprintf(check_command, sizeof(check_command), "which %s", editor_command);
    FILE *fp = popen(check_command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return 0;  // popen failed
    }
    int found = (fgetc(fp) != EOF);
    pclose(fp);
    return found;
}

I use popen to check if my pipe-opening command failed. I definitely have VSCode installed, but it’s not being detected or opened upon request. I haven’t tested it on other machines yet, but for reference, I am currently using macOS Sonoma 14.5.
I also attempted using:
system("which <editor> > /dev/null 2>&1");

to check for the editor’s existence to no avail. I have similar functions for Vim and Neovim, but those seem to work fine. GPT couldn't even help :/


have you tried checking within the PATH environment variable? I figure that would be the fastest and most portable way
